# Problem checking if char is right or worng

Tags: c++

The code below is for a hangman game. I'm a beginner, as you can probably tell. I know it has to do with the second `for` loop in the `while` loop, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to check if it is wrong. When I try, it gives me lower and lower lives. Please help.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

void playgame();

int main(){
    bool gameloop;
    std::cout<<"1: Play Game"<<std::endl<<"2: End Game"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>gameloop;
    if (!gameloop){
        return 0;
    }

    while (gameloop){
        ///Displays board
        playgame();
    }
}

void playgame(){
    int wordchange = (rand()%10);
    std::string word;
    switch (wordchange){
        case 0:
            word = "orange";
            break;
        case 1:
            word = "apple";
            break;
        case 2:
            word = "strawberry";
            break;
        case 3:
            word = "mango";
            break;
        case 4:
            word = "kiwi";
            break;
        case 5:
            word = "grape";
            break;
        case 6:
            word = "pear";
            break;
        case 7:
            word = "plum";
            break;
        case 8:
            word = "raspberry";
            break;
        case 9:
            word = "grapefruit";
            break;
    }
    ///Variables
    bool gameon = true; 
    int stringsize= word.size();
    char guess;
    int lives = 6;

    ///makes the answer array 
    char playerans[stringsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsize; ++i){
        playerans[i] = '#';
    }

    /// Game Questioning
    while (gameon){
        std::cout<<"Lives Left: "<<lives<<"\n";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < stringsize; ++i){ //Prints out answer array
            std::cout<<playerans[i];
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
        std::cin>>guess;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringsize; ++i){
            if (guess == word[i] && playerans[i] == 351){
                playerans[i] = guess;
            } else if (playerans[i] != 351 and playerans[i] != word[i]){
                std::cout<<"H";
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code line-by-line, with a debugger, while observing the values of variables, at each execution step, while taking note of when the code does something, that deviates from your expectations?

Comment: `playerans[i] == 351` can't be right.  Did you mean `playerans[i] == '#'`?  And again two lines later.

Comment: I can't seem to get a debugger on geany, it's on the raspberry pi 3 b+. (My computer is too slow to run anything). The 315 is the value I got when I did the following

Comment: Int a = a; std::cout<<a;

Comment: https://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html  I'd suggest you find out if that's supported; else you're going to have to start learning how to use gdb directly

Comment: `int a = a;` initializes `a` with the current value of `a`, and `a`hasn't been initialized so it doesn't have a value yet. Did you mean `int = 'a';`` to get the value of character a?

Comment: A note on the computer being too slow: I ran gdb on 16 Mhz 386 back in the 90's. Then I wised up and bought a copy of Turbo C with the <expletive deleted>ing amazing Turbo debugger. Anyway, If your computer 's slower than my old 16 Mhz 386-SX, I salute you for trying. But seriously Doritos have more firepower these days.

Comment: I messed up on the line, I meant to say int a = '#';. Sorry about that. Also the computer is new too, I can't believe how slow it is, it takes a minute to print "Hello World" lol.

Comment: I figured out what is wrong. It has to do with playerans not being changed, so when I compare it to see if it is wrong, it will always be right. I'm just trying to figure out how to fix it. Thank you for all the support :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using an array. In which every element was false. One would be proven true if guess was right. Then a for loop would check to see if any elements were true. If one was true the guess is correct, if non were true then the guess was wrong. Thank you for all the support. Have a magnificent day :)

Answer (score 0):

Expression `playerans[i] == 351` is always false. `char` can only have values between -128 and 127. Instead, use the actual character: `playerans[i] == '#'`.

Comment: `char` can also be between 0 and 255. Its signedness is implementation-defined.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. One of the problems I was having was just have been due to that.